# Add images to screen programmatically

Tags: android, image, button, onclicklistener, display

In one of the activity of my app, I have a button where I want to display an image with each button click. For example:

[image]

By clicking the button of my activity, an image appears on screen as shown.

[image]

The second and following clicks on the button will results in the new image to append accordingly.

[image]

I would like to have some suggestion on how do I achieve this.

Comment: As a trick you can make a recyclerview, every time you click the button, one item of recyclerview will be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made something similar to this but with TextView. Basically I did this:

**XML:**

For my case I made `TableLayout` Ex:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/existedTableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_standard">

    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/number_text"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**Activity**

Note: Change it to ImageView for your case

```
/* //Get the TableLayout. Ex:
    private TableLayout existedTableLayout = findViewById(R.id.existedTableLayout);
*/
/* Make onClickListerner to call below function */
private void addTableRowDynamically() {
        //Make new Row
        TableRow newRow= new TableRow(this);

        TextView newNoTextView = new TextView(this);
        //some TextView method, do your research about ImageView
        newNoTextView.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(0,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
        newNoTextView.setText("this is text");
        newNoTextView.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_DeviceDefault_Large);

        // Add the TextView to the newRow
        newRow.addView(newNoTextView);

        // Add the newRow which contain the TextView to the TableLayout, below
        existedTableLayout.addView(newRow, existedTableLayout.getChildCount());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a vertical `LineaLayout`  and add views dynamically:

```
private void createViews() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
            view = new ImageView(context);
            int width = 300;
            int height = 50;
            view.setPadding(18, 10, 0, 0);
            view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));
            view.setId(i);
            view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("someColor"));
            viewList.add(view);
        }
    }

     Rect rectf = new Rect();
        for (ImageView view : viewList) {
                    view.getGlobalVisibleRect(rectf);
                    coordinates.add(rectf.bottom);
                }
```